# MySQL - Delete corrupt database issue

Tags: mysql

A database became corrupted, and I am unable to drop the database. I can create another database and drop - no worries. It is a case when I try to drop I get a lost connection to server error.

If I delete `mysql/data/mydatabase` and recreate mydatabase files I am still having issues with the new created database.

If I create a new database with different name and work with this, there are no issues.

How can I completely remove all files associated with the corrupted database?

Answer (score -2):

Try dropping it through the MySQL command line:

```
DROP DATABASE dbname;
```

Comment: yep same issue lost connection to server. If i create a new database and delete no worries. There is no tables in the database i am trying to drop.